# How to install curses in anaconda for windows 7

Tags: python, anaconda, curses, tflearn

Whenever I try to install curses, I get this error:

[image]

Can anybody please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post terminal output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Comment: I for one can't see the error as the image hosting URL is blocked at the institution I'm accessing to SE from.

Answer (score 0):

Try the conda install, such like

```
conda install package_name==version
```